# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

While writing cide for Selenium with Java in intellij, I am getting this error.
This issue is occuring for new projecting. Old projects are working fine.Though I am copying the same data from old project to new project.

Code:

```java
@Test
    public void testcase1() throws IOException {
        driver = initializeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(props.getProperty("url"));

    }
```

Error:

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotSelectableException

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes.<clinit>(ErrorCodes.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>(ErrorHandler.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.<init>(ErrorHandler.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
    at resources.Base.initializeDriver(Base.java:28)
    at testcases.HomePageTest.testcase1(HomePageTest.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:220)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:945)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotSelectableException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: There is "Class not Found" error. So, most probably you have not connected  org.openqa.selenium as a library to your project.

Comment: I have created Maven project and added Maven dependency instead of Jars. This s the remaining code where i am getting error:

Answer (score 0):

It was Dependency issue.Though I had added selenium dependencies in pom.xml file but it did not get added successfully.
So issue was occuring.
If you also get this issue,
Open terminal, navigate till path of the project and execute command "mvn install"
and then run your program.